# Display an ashx image using jQuery?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, colorbox

I've been trying to use the jQuery plugin [Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) to display images I have in my DB through an ashx file.  Unfortunately it just spits a bunch of gibberish at the top of the page and no image.  Can this be done?  Here is what I have so far:

```
   $(document).ready
   (
       function () 
       {
           $("a[rel='cbImg']").colorbox(); 
       }
   );
...
<a rel="cbImg" href="HuntImage.ashx?id=15">Click to see image</a>
```

UPDATE:

My ashx file is writing the binary out:

```
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/bmp";
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(ba);
```

Comment: What does your ashx return a URL for the image or the binary image?

Comment: If it is the binary, i think you would want to have the actual src for the image by the handler.

Comment: the ashx writes the binary for the image.  @Stefan, can you expand on that?

Comment: What I meant was that if the response from your handler is the binary for the image, like you say it is.  It would be the src for your img tag.  However, if colorbox does not use an image tag.  My suggestion does not help you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Colorbox has an option 'photo'. If you set this to true in your constructor then it will force it to render the photo.

```
$(target).colorbox({photo: true});
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll take a look at this.

Comment: @Abe: It worked for me with my handler. I'm using /image.axd as my url but I can't see why it shouldn't work for you. BTW my colorbox version is 1.3.16 you might want to upgrade...

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting the  src attribute in the client side.

```
<img src="HuntImage.ashx?id=15" ..../>
```

The handler

```
public class ImageRequestHandler: IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.Clear();

            if(context.Request.QueryString.Count != 0)
            {
        //Get the stored image and write in the response.
                var storedImage = context.Session[_Default.STORED_IMAGE] as byte[];
                if (storedImage != null)
                {
                    Image image = GetImage(storedImage);
                    if (image != null)
                    {
                        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                        image.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private Image GetImage(byte[] storedImage)
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream(storedImage);
            return Image.FromStream(stream);
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return false; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean.  Could you give me an example?

Comment: @Abe Miessler: Edited the answer.

Comment: @Cybernate: The img src can be set onclick event of the client. Then the image will load.

Comment: OP is using colorbox plugin, can you exemplify in that context?

Comment: Well i'm not getting the giberish but it's not showing anything at all now.

Comment: After some more poking around it looks like colorbox only works with a anchor tag, so switching to an image tag won't work.

Comment: @Abe Miessler: How about the <img> inside the anchor tag. <a href=..><img src="HuntImage.ashx?id=5"></a>

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I can't do what I am trying using colorbox with an ashx image.  If anyone finds a way please post it here.

I considered deleting the question but I will leave it up incase someone else runs into the same issue.

Comment: See James South's answer, it hits the spot!

Answer (score 0):

Find this function around line 124 (colorbox 1.3.15)

```
// Checks an href to see if it is a photo.
// There is a force photo option (photo: true) for hrefs that cannot be matched by this regex.
function isImage(url) {
    return settings.photo || /\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|bmp)(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(\.*))?$/i.test(url);
}
```

On line 127, add `|ashx` after bmp in `(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|bmp)` so it reads like this:

```
// Checks an href to see if it is a photo.
// There is a force photo option (photo: true) for hrefs that cannot be matched by this regex.
function isImage(url) {
    return settings.photo || /\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|bmp|ashx)(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(\.*))?$/i.test(url);
}
```

This is working just fine for me in Sitecore 6.2 :)

Comment: Very interesting.  I'll give this a shot and let you know how it goes.